# Local State in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, state, let

Newbie question in Common Lisp:

How to make my procedure to return distinct procedural object with its own local binding each time call? Currently, I use let to create the local state, but two function calls are sharing the same local state. Here is the code,

```
(defun make-acc ()
  (let ((balance 100))
    (defun withdraw (amount)
      (setf balance (- balance amount))
      (print balance))
    (defun deposit (amount)
      (setf balance (+ balance amount))
      (print balance))
    (lambda (m)
      (cond ((equal m 'withdraw)
              (lambda (x) (withdraw x)))
            ((equal m 'deposit)
              (lambda (x) (deposit x)))))))

;; test

(setf peter-acc (make-acc))

(setf paul-acc (make-acc))

(funcall (funcall peter-acc 'withdraw) 10)
;; Give 90

(funcall (funcall paul-acc 'withdraw) 10)
;; Expect 90 but give 80
```

Should I do it in another way? Is my way of writing wrong? Can someone pls help me to clear this doubt? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that Common Lisp has an object system, so there is usually no need to model state via lambdas.

Answer (score 6):

Note that, even after the `defun`-is-global problem is dealt with, you need far less machinery than you have to do something like this.  For instance:

```
(defun make-account (balance)
  (lambda (op amount)
    (ecase op
      ((withdraw)
       (decf balance amount))
      ((deposit)
       (incf balance amount)))))

(defun account-operation (account op &rest args-to-op)
  (apply account op args-to-op))
```

Then

```
> (setf joe-acct (make-account 10))
#<Closure 1 subfunction of make-account 4060010B54>

> (setf mary-acct (make-account 100))
#<Closure 1 subfunction of make-account 4060010C94>

> (account-operation joe-acct 'withdraw 10)
0

> (account-operation mary-acct 'deposit 10)
110
```

Obviously `account-operation` is just a convenience.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you want object orientation?

```
(defclass account ()
  ((balance :initarg :balance
            :initform 100
            :accessor balance)))

(defmethod withdraw ((acc account) amount)
  (decf (balance acc) amount))

(defmethod deposit ((acc account) amount)
  (incf (balance acc) amount))
```

Usage:

```
(defparameter alice-account (make-instance 'account))
(withdraw alice-account 25) ;; => 75
(balance alice-account) ;; => 75
```

We can create accounts with another balance:

```
(defparameter bob-account (make-instance 'account :balance 90))
```

For more, I suggest the Cookbook: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/clos.html

Answer (score 4):

A general rule is that `defun` should be used only when defining a function at top level. To define local functions the two special operators `flet` and `labels` can be used ([manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_flet_.htm)).

For instance:

```
(defun make-acc ()
  (let ((balance 100))
    (flet ((withdraw (amount)
             (setf balance (- balance amount))
             (print balance))
           (deposit (amount)
             (setf balance (+ balance amount))
             (print balance)))
      (lambda (m)
        (cond ((equal m 'withdraw)
               (lambda (x) (withdraw x)))
              ((equal m 'deposit)
               (lambda (x) (deposit x))))))))
```

`labels` is like `flet`, but it is used when there are recursive definitions.

Then you don't need to return functions inside the function returned by `make-acc`, but in it you can simply execute the required operation:

```
(defun make-acc ()
  (let ((balance 100))
    (flet ((withdraw (amount)
             (setf balance (- balance amount))
             (print balance))
           (deposit (amount)
             (setf balance (+ balance amount))
           (print balance)))
      (lambda (m x)
        (cond ((equal m 'withdraw)
               (withdraw x))
              ((equal m 'deposit)
               (deposit x)))))))
```

The call will be more simple and will return the expected value:

```
CL-USER> (setf paul-acc (make-acc))
#<CCL:COMPILED-LEXICAL-CLOSURE (:INTERNAL MAKE-ACC) #x3020021640AF>
CL-USER> (funcall paul-acc 'withdraw 10)

90 
90
CL-USER> (funcall paul-acc 'withdraw 10)

80 
80
```

Finally, if you want you can also return two different functions to perform deposit and withdrawal on the account:

```
(defun make-acc (initial-amount)
  (let ((balance initial-amount))
    (flet ((withdraw (amount)
             (setf balance (- balance amount))
             (print balance))
           (deposit (amount)
             (setf balance (+ balance amount))
             (print balance)))
          (values #'withdraw #'deposit))))
```

using this for instance as:

```
(multiple-value-bind (paul-withdraw paul-deposit)
    (make-acc 100)
  (funcall paul-withdraw 10)
  (funcall paul-withdraw 10))
```

Answer (score 3):

The only serious problem here is `defun` that in common lisp is not used to define local functions.

You could for example use `lambda`s for those operations, especially as you want to return lambdas...

```
(defun make-acc ()
  (let* ((balance 100)
         (withdraw (lambda (amount)
                     (setf balance (- balance amount))
                     (print balance)))
         (deposit (lambda (amount)
                    (setf balance (+ balance amount))
                    (print balance))))
    (lambda (m)
      (cond
        ((equal m 'withdraw) withdraw)
        ((equal m 'deposit) deposit)))))
```

Note that I used `let*` instead of `let` because you need to be able to see `balance` in the two following bindings.